# Visual editor in comments with custom buttons

Tags: visual-editor

I have loaded WP visual editor in comments using `wp_editor` function and I want to customize the height and buttons of the editor, also it would be much better to show Text mode/tab only and disable the Visual mode/tab.

Here my code:

```
<?PHP
    $settings = array(
                      false,        // wpautop
                      false,        // media_buttons
                      'comment',    // textarea_name
                      5,            // textarea_rows
                      'None',       // tabindex
                      'None',       // editor_css
                      'test',       // editor_class
                      true,         // teeny
                      false,
                      true,         // tinymce
                      true          // quicktags
                     )

?>
<?php wp_editor( 'Enter your comments here', get_the_ID(), $settings); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solutions, anyone else can benefit from it.

- [Remove Specific Buttons from WordPress Editor](http://codebing.com/remove-specific-buttons-from-wordpress-editor/)
- [Remove HTML editor and visual/HTML tabs from TinyMCE](http://codebing.com/remove-html-editor-and-visualhtml-tabs-from-tinymce/)